# How does one do a time lapse video in the public?

Tags: timelapse

How does one do a time lapse video in the public? I can understand if the time lapse is taken from indoor looking out to a window or something like that. But how does one take, say, a time lapse looking up into the Eiffel tower? Do you literally sit there and watch the tripod for 4 hours straight?

I guess same question to those multi days time lapse. Is there a special way of securing the equipment without getting it stolen or knocked over?

Comment: Google with words "camera security box" for which the most hits cover boxes that secure a camera, though some pages on security cameras will naturally pop up too.

Comment: For the really long shots, pick up a Pelican case, drill out a hole for your lens, add in some type of glass, seal with caulk, lock with a masterlock or similar to something that can't move.

Answer (score 8):

If you don't want your equipment stolen, yes, you (and/or a friend) stay there for however long it takes.

Very long term shots usually make use of some kind of secure box, bolted or chained in place. Depending on the location this can require permission from the relevant authorities.